# How to display a variable as a total in an INPUT FIELD instead of a SPAN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having difficult displaying the contents of a variable in a total input field. Basically this code is functioning which is great:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#product-unit-val, #total-unit-sales, #number-reps').change(function() {
    var total = parseInt($("#product-unit-val").val()) *  
                parseInt($("#total-unit-sales").val()) * 
                parseInt($("#number-reps").val());
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $("#sales-val").html(total);
    }
  });
});
</script>

Average product unit value <input type="text" id="product-unit-val" /><br/>
Total unit sales value <input type="text" id="total-unit-sales" /><br/>
Number of reps <input type="text" id="number-reps" /><br/>
Total sales value <span id="sales-val"></span>$​​​
```

However I want to display the total value in an input field like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#product-unit-val, #total-unit-sales, #number-reps').change(function() {
    var total = parseInt($("#product-unit-val").val()) *  
                parseInt($("#total-unit-sales").val()) * 
                parseInt($("#number-reps").val());
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $("#sales-val").html(total);
    }
  });
});
</script>

Average product unit value <input type="text" id="product-unit-val" /><br/>
Total unit sales value <input type="text" id="total-unit-sales" /><br/>
Number of reps <input type="text" id="number-reps" /><br/>
Total sales value <input type ="text" id="sales-val"/>​
```

Am I missing the obvious? I just can't seem to get this working.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to change the value of an input :

```
$("#sales-val").val(total);
```

But be careful with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), always specify the radix :

```
parseInt('09') == 0
parseInt('09', 10) == 9
```